# Android Material Design Collapsing Toolbar with ImageView and Information Below

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I was looking through Google's Material Design guidelines and I saw these screens below that I had some questions about.

[image]

The questions are about the purple area below the collapsable imageview. The first question is, when this design is used is the purple area with the text part of the collapsing toolbar and if so does the text "It wasn't a dream" become the toolbar title when collpased? The next question is, if the purple area is part of the collapsing toolbar how would I implement it? Would I just add a TextView in my CollapsingToolbarLayout?